# Python: Splitting an input of unknown length and creating an array

Tags: python, arrays, split, strip

In Python how would I go about creating an array containing the split input of something in this format:

ex.)

```
(1,2,3)&(6,8,10)&(2,5)&(29,8,6)
```

-the input would be any number of these tuples.

-I'd split at '&' and strip the parenthesis

-then I'd like to turn it into an array
in this case:

```
array=
 [[1,2,3],
 [6,8,10],
 [2,5],
 [29,8,6]]
```

Comment: Is `something` a string?

Answer (score 0):

If Something is a string, you could do this.

```
something = "(1,2,3)&(6,8,10)&(2,5)&(29,8,6)"

words = something.split('&')

for i,x in enumerate(words):
    words[i] = x.replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

or use list comprehension instead of for loop like,

```
words[:] = [x.replace('(','').replace(')','') for x in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have such a rigid structure, the solution may be as follows

```
s = "(1,2,3)&(6,8,10)&(2,5)&(29,8,6)"
l = [list(map(int, t[1:-1].split(','))) for t in s.split('&')]
print(l)  # [[1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 10], [2, 5], [29, 8, 6]]
```

where first you split the string by "&" and then you split the substrings, starting at second and ending and one before the last position, by "," and `map` them as `int` or any other number type

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to go if you need to take care of changing input string

```
data = '(1,2,3)&(6,8,10)&(2,5)&(29,8,6)'
a = []
for i in data.split('&'):
    a.append([int(j) for j in i[i.find('(')+1:i.find(')')].split(',')])
print(a)  #[[1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 10], [2, 5], [29, 8, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
>>> def to_list(s):
...     return [int(i) for i in s.strip('()').split(',')]
... 
>>> data = '(1,2,3)&(6,8,10)&(2,5)&(29,8,6)'
>>> [to_list(item) for item in data.split('&')]
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 10], [2, 5], [29, 8, 6]]
```